# Store git credentials permanently and encrypted using a keystore in Ubuntu

Tags: password, encryption, git

Storing git credentials with the command:

```
git config credential.helper store
```

stores them unencrypted in a plain text under `~/.git-credentials`.

In [MacOS](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/#platform-mac) and [Windows](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/#platform-windows), *GitHub Help* suggests to use keystores which encrypt your credentials using `osxkeychain` and `wincred` respectively. In Linux however there is [no mention](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/#platform-linux) about how to encrypt your git credentials. Are you aware of a way on how to do that ?

Comment: As an alternative you can authenticate with your ssh key which is more secure

Comment: @daumie how is it more secure? `access_token` are giving access only to git over http, not ssh, it is made to expire and be renewed. It is as much portable as an `access_token` except it is harder to remember by hearth.

Comment: IIUC, access_token is a form of password, sent to the server over TLS. If the TLS security of HTTPS connection is somehow compromised (computer got rogue CA root in trust store, sadly common with corporate spyware / CA compromise / revoked cert used / openssl bug / ...), I attacker could steal it and get access.  SSH uses asymmetric crypto such that even if connection gets decrypted, attacker does _not_ learn the secret key.  That's one point, don't know which is safer in practice...

Comment: counterpoint: almost nobody checks SSH machine certs in practice (example script: https://github.com/cben/myenv/blob/master/check-github-ssh-fingerprint.sh, see links there), people just press Yes on first connection, so that's a real risk of MITM compared to HTTPS certifying server domain.  It's just the consequences of MITM are less catastrophic. ⚖